# Update values from one array to another

Tags: knockout.js

I have two arrays (and bear in mind I'm pretty new to Knockout):

```
"Instructions": {
    "Instruction": [{
        "Text": "Text 1",
        "Type": "REFERENCE",
        "SequenceNo": "1",
        },
        {
        "Text": "Text 2",
        "Type": "REFERENCE",
        "SequenceNo": "2",
    }]
}


"References": [{
    "Text": "New Text 1",
    "Type": "REFERENCE",
    "SequenceNo": "1"
    },
    {
    "Text": "New Text 2",
    "Type": "REFERENCE",
    "SequenceNo": "2"
}]
```

I want to update the text values in instructions based on the sequence number (sequenceno) in references.

So for SequenceNo 1 in instructions, the text should be "New Text 1".

How would I go about doing that in knockout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you viewmodel, you have two observableArrays and assuming data is filled

```
var vm = {
    var self = this;

    self.Instructions = ko.observableArray();
    self.References= ko.observableArray();

    //to update the values from References to Instruction 
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.References, function(data){
        ko.utils.arrayForeach(self.Instructions, function(item){
            if( data.SequenceNo == item.SequenceNo ){
                item.Text = data.Text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```